# undefined is not an object windows safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a div with a class named `Playbtn`. When I run the page in Safari on Windows I get an error saying `btn` is undefined (`btn` is a global variable, if that makes a difference).

```
var btn = document.getElementById('toggle');
...
if (btn.className == 'Playbtn') {
    btn.className = 'Pausebtn';
}
```

Html

```
<div id="toggle" class="PlayBtn" onclick="PlayPause()"></div>
```

The application runs perfectly in all other browser so why is this error happening?

Comment: Show your HTML. Sounds like `toggle` is not a valid ID, thus `btn` is not assigned to anything.

Comment: Safari for windows? Solution = ignore

Comment: Your html is invalid. Why did you wrap the inner div in single quotes?

Comment: not sure how to post html in question placed there so i placed it there so that it would allow me sorry should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
<div id="toggle" class="PlayBtn" onclick="PlayPause()"></div>
```

insted of this,

```
<'div id="toggle" class="PlayBtn" onclick="PlayPause()"></div'>
```

it may work?

Comment: You don't seem confident, at all... lol. You should also explain WHAT/WHY changed in your answers, instead of just saying, "Use this..."